# Interpretation of omega as a reliability measure for broad constructs

Tags: reliability

At first i have to say that i'm a statistics rookie having a hard time to comprehend all the concepts and interrelations. So please cut me some slack ;)

I conducted a survey that collects data about energy knowledge. So far 465 students filled out the corresponding questionnaire with 60 items. The constructs i like to map are very broad. There are 22 items related to everyday energy knowledge (EK) like energy use on a private or social level. The remaining 38 items pose questions about the scientific energy concept (SEC). The items have a closed multiple choice format. The test should be a diagnostic test as well as an achievement test for a following quasiexperimental intervention study.

I checked content validity with expert interviews and checked the cognitive validity with think aloud interviews. The interviews were conducted with students of the target group. As a result misleading items were removed from the questionnaire.

Because of the breadth of the construct i assume that the data is not unidimensional or say it another way that the data is not sufficiently explained by a single factor. Therefore i assess the reliability not with Cronbach's alpha but rather with omega as proposed by McDonald (Peters 2014).

The output of the summary of the omega function (Revelle 2013) for **SEC** is

```
Omega
Alpha:                 0.87
G.6:                   0.89
Omega Hierarchical:    0.61
Omega H asymptotic:    0.69
Omega Total            0.88

With eigenvalues of:
    g   F1*   F2*   F3*
4.607 2.551 1.450 0.015
The degrees of freedom for the model is 592  and the fit was  2.3
The number of observations was  465  with Chi Square =  1021  with prob <  0

The root mean square of the residuals is  0.05
The df corrected root mean square of the residuals is  0.05

RMSEA and the  0.1 confidence intervals are  0.041 0.035 0.044
BIC =  -2615Explained Common Variance of the general factor =  0.53

 Total, General and Subset omega for each subset
                                                 g  F1*  F2*  F3*
Omega total for total scores and subscales    0.88 0.83 0.75 0.27
Omega general for total scores and subscales  0.61 0.38 0.56 0.27
Omega group for total scores and subscales    0.18 0.45 0.19 0.00
```

For **EEK** the output is

```
Omega
Alpha:                 0.63
G.6:                   0.66
Omega Hierarchical:    0.49
Omega H asymptotic:    0.75
Omega Total            0.66

With eigenvalues of:
     g    F1*    F2*    F3*
2.2109 0.0095 0.5484 0.6264
The degrees of freedom for the model is 168  and the fit was  0.51
The number of observations was  465  with Chi Square =  233  with prob <  0

The root mean square of the residuals is  0.04
The df corrected root mean square of the residuals is  0.05

RMSEA and the  0.1 confidence intervals are  0.03 0.019 0.037
BIC =  -799Explained Common Variance of the general factor =  0.65

 Total, General and Subset omega for each subset
                                                 g  F1*  F2*  F3*
Omega total for total scores and subscales    0.66 0.74 0.54 0.24
Omega general for total scores and subscales  0.49 0.74 0.30 0.07
Omega group for total scores and subscales    0.15 0.00 0.24 0.16
```

What i know is that omega-hierarchical explains the variance of the general factor. The variance is at the same time an estimate for the reliablity. Therefore both scales map the "true scores" of the construct not very well. However i have problems to talk about "true scores" here since an item-score is more of a linear combination of several factors. I really have a hard time interpreting the results.

On a conceptual level I would argue that the knowledge of the sample is strongly fragmented in both domains. The participants don't seem to have coherent knowledge structures abut the topic. However the knowledge is more coherent in the **ECK** than in the **EEK** domain.

Anyhow a low reliability eg. a low loading on a general factor is bad if one wants to explain individual differences. Is it possible to find arguments that support the use of the test as an achievement test to resolve inter-individual differences in test-scores?

At the same time I have a similar problem interpreting correlation with covariates like socio economic status etc. From a theoretical standpoint it makes no sense to interpret them if one correlate (the test score) is mostly explained by the error variance and not by the variance of the true score!?

I guess everybody notice that i'm pretty confused about the whole topic. I would be very grateful to receive some comments about it.

May the statisticians be with me :)

---

Peters, G.-J. Y. (2014). The alpha and the omega of scale reliability and validity. The European Health Psychologist, 16(2), 56–69.

Revelle, W. (2013). Using R and the psych package to find ω, 1–18.